# webViewDidFinishLoad: Missing Protocol?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Can anyone just clarify this for me, I was under the impression that to use webViewDidFinishLoad: I would have to conform my class to `<UIWebViewDelegate>`. However I forgot to do this but found it still works where I was expecting an error/warning. Can anyone explain for me?

```
-(void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    // do stuff ...
}
```

much appreciated,

Gary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The methods in `UIWebViewDelegate` are supposed to be optionally implemented. If `UIWebView` would force you to implement the protocol by testing wether the delegate [conforms](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/conformsToProtocol:) to it, you'd always have the annoying warnings about your class not fully implementing the protocol.
`UIWebViewDelegate` effectively exists for self-documentation and in case you want to be warned about not fully implementing it. If you want these warnings, see [Adopting a Protocol](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocProtocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH15-SW3).